# trouble getting variables shown after onClick event

Tags: javascript, html

My question is why when i click the button the only thing getting shown is this "Pricelist" and all the other lines with variables in it get omitted.

```
function showmessage() {
    var sendcost, totalcost;
    if (document.pricelist.total.value<11) {
        sendcost = 3; 
    }   
    else {
        sendcost = 2; 
    }   
    if (document.pricelist.option.checked) {
        sendcost = parseInt(document.pricelist.option.value) + parseInt(sendcost);
    }
    totalcost = parseInt(sendcost) + parseInt(document.pricelist.total.value);

    document.write("Pricelist","</br>");
    document.write("Products price: "+document.pricelist.total.value+"</br>");
    document.write("Send fee: "+sendcost+"</br>");
    document.write("Total cost: "+totalcost+"</br>");
}
```

```html
<form name="pricelist">
Tuna Salad = 4 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="4" onchange="checkTotal()" /></br>
Pasta = 13 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="13" onchange="checkTotal()" /></br>
Milk = 3 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="3" onchange="checkTotal()" /></br>
Chocolate = 2 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2" onchange="checkTotal()" /></br>
Same day delivery<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="5" /></br>
Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/>
<input type="button" value="Procceed to checkout" onclick='return showmessage();' />
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code. Notice the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` when called after the page loads will destroy the entire page, therefore there will be no form with name pricelist anymore therefore `document.pricelist.total.value` will cause `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`, which causes your script to terminate prematurely.

I'd suggest using something other than `document.write`.

But to avoid the current error just save the value of `document.pricelist.total.value` to a variable before its destroyed.

```
var value = document.pricelist.total.value;
document.write("Pricelist","</br>");
document.write("Products price: "+value+"</br>");
document.write("Send fee: "+sendcost+"</br>");
document.write("Total cost: "+totalcost+"</br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it stops working after displaying "Products Price:" is because of syntax errors with the next 2 lines of code.

Update:

```
document.write("Send fee: "+sendcost+"</br>);
document.write("Total cost: "+totalcost+"</br>;
```

to:

```
document.write("Send fee: "+sendcost+"</br>");
document.write("Total cost: "+totalcost+"</br>");
```

Also update:

```
document.write("Pricelist","</br>");
```

to:

```
document.write("Pricelist</br>");
```

And then fix your malformed `</br>` tags to be `<br />`

Comment: yeah i made a mistake there and edit it to the correct one but still it keeps on showing only Pricelist.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug for debugging. Really excellent tool for Firefox 
http://getfirebug.com/

Chrome and Internet Explorer also have a quite good internal debugging tool
Press F12 to open it.

Those tools let you debug visually - you can step through each script command and watch what happens